# input output read/write frequency

Tags: frequency, transfer-function, nyquist, control-systems

I am trying to identify a system based on input/output response and thereby estimate a transfer function. 
I generated a frequency sweep function in Mathematica which gives me the discrete values of a frequency sweep.

```
g[t_] := 0.799760*Sin[2 Pi (3 t/333.3 + 1) t];
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 1000000000000000000000000000000}]
g[#] & /@ Range[0, 5, 0.001]
```

So now I have a bunch of data but at what rate should I input it into the system, and at what rate should I read it?

How should I apply Nyquist frequency rule here?

Answer (score -1):

Best to base it on the highest frequency response you anticipate for the system and implement twice that frequency with the samples you input and the data you read.